# Trying to get this .js lightbox to display upon the load of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

This Lightbox looks lovely,

http://dev7studios.com/nivo-lightbox/#/demos

but I need the lightbox to fire up upon the load of the page.

Answer (score 1):

After adding the elements on the page add the following to the

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').nivoLightbox();
});
</script>
```

This should activate the lightbox on the anchor () on page load.

For opening the page with image already opened,

```
$( "a.firstImage" ).trigger( "click" );
```

Ref: http://dev7studios.com/nivo-lightbox/#/documentation

Comment: Sorry, that's not exactly working. I've added it, but I still have to click to activate it. I'd love if the lightbox was activated on page load.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, you could do something like this